# What should I do to see a code of particular object, not result of that object in R?

Tags: r

For example, I wrote code as below;

```
x<-seq(0,1,length=1000)
```

(sorry, I don't know how I should exactly call concept of this `x`…)

On this occasion, I wanna see `seq(0,1,length=1000)` or `x<-seq(0,1,length=1000)` in result screen, not result of that `seq` like `0.000000000 0.001001001 0.002002002 …`.

At first, I used `x$call`, but it seems `$call` is only work with `lm`. Is there any way to get the result that I want?

Comment: Only some things store the `call` as an attributes or member of its entirety. `lm` is one that does, `seq` is one (among most) that do not.

Comment: Have a read of `?call` maybe - `cl <- call("seq", 0, 1, length=10)` and then `eval(cl)` It's not really what you want, but close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll a function that takes a quoted expression and outputs both the call and the result in a list, then call the relevant list element as needed.

```
f <- function(expr) list(call = expr, value = eval(expr))

### call f() with a quoted expression
out <- f(quote(x <- seq(0, 1, length=1000)))

### get the call
out$call
# x <- seq(0, 1, length = 1000)

### get the (first few) values
head(out$value)
# [1] 0.000000000 0.001001001 0.002002002 0.003003003 0.004004004 0.005005005
```

Another option builds on @thelatemail's comment.  We can create a call via `call` and then evaluate it if we need to.

```
cl <- call("<-", quote(x), quote(seq(0, 1, length = 1000)))
cl
# x <- seq(0, 1, length = 1000)
eval(cl)
head(x)
# [1] 0.000000000 0.001001001 0.002002002 0.003003003 0.004004004 0.005005005
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment. Then is there no way that I can the inside of `x` without defining other objects like `cl` or `out`? Actually, I want to see inside of `x` by using `x` itself, and using other commands.